# Hibernate xml mapping oto, otm, mto, mtm

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, mapping

i'm trying to understand how to map with xml in hibernate.. But I don't really understand how to map one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one or many-to-many..

For example, how can I map this?

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,targetEntity = AnotherClass.class,mappedBy = "var_anotherclass")
private AnotherClass another;
```

Please.

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you have a look at the XML mapping documentation? And why do you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: @Thomas Well, I'm trying to improve hibernate class mapping, I read in a page that xml mapping is faster than class mapping.. So I wanna see if there is a true difference(and learn something new about hibernate in the process)